# No metadata found

Tags: python, pyqt5

**Hello**
I'm on Windows
Recently i uninstalled PyQt5. When i tried to install i got an error

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.15.6)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5-5.15.6.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

I tried to reinstall, but...

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pyqt5==5.15.6
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.6
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pyqt5
  Attempting uninstall: pyqt5
    WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
    Found existing installation: pyqt5 5.15.6
ERROR: Cannot uninstall pyqt5 5.15.6, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pyqt5==5.15.6'.
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O! So have you followed the instruction of `pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pyqt5==5.15.6` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: as per @David, or alternatively. `python -m pip install pyqt5`...

Comment: @D.L The OP already tried that by doing `pip install pyqt5` which failed. I don't think adding `python -m` will make it work?

Comment: @David, it guarantees installing to the correct version. But i do agree that the suggestion in the error would the be first method.  (i would still add `python -m` in front of that)...  [installing python modules](https://youtu.be/0C-Nssu3XqE)